# Autoware ROSBAG Demo doesn't work as expected

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, i'm trying to create a ndt_mapping using our bag file, but isn't successful.

First, according to this page
[(here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ss6Blrz23h8)

1. Go to Simulation tab and select arosbag
2. Click "Play" and click "Pause
3. Click Computing tab and select ndt_mapping
4. Click RViz button
5. Go back to Simulation tab and click Pause to start mapping

And no point cloud is shown in rviz.

I test the ROSBAG Demo according to this page
[(here)](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/ROSBAG-Demo)

And no point cloud is shown in rviz, too.

I using ubuntu 18.04/melodic
Autoware:1.12 (use source install)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336618/autoware-rosbag-demo-doesn%27t-work-as-expected/) by [scarlet191101](https://answers.ros.org/users/48518/scarlet191101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-02**:
To visualize using rviz, you should set TFs properly. I guess this is the cause.

Could you try these additional steps?

1. Click "TF" in Setup tab

   - for /base_link to /velodyne
2. Click "TF" in Map tab after Referencing tf.launch in sample moriyama data

   - for /world to /map
3. Re-launch `ndt_mapping`

   - Just in case

If not resolved, please give us these information.

1. Results of `rosrun tf view_frames` (frames.pdf)
2. ScreenShots of your runtime_manager and rviz
3. (If any error message is shown in rviz) the error messages

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-08**:
@scarlet191101 Have you solved this problem?

**Comment by [scarlet191101](https://answers.ros.org/users/48518/scarlet191101/) on 2019-11-08**:
I don’t have much time to try recently.

Click "TF" I have tried, but it is not effective

I don’t know why I often crash when I last tested.

I will test it when I have time.

Thank you~

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-13**:
same issue as above. I tried your suggestions but got this error when relaunching MAP.

RLException: while processing /home//.autoware/data/tf/tf.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home//.autoware/data/tf/tf.launch'

answers to your questions above.
1)
dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)

Detected dot version 2.40
frames.pdf generated
I don't know how to attach a file here but here is a cut and paste of the .pdf.  It shows world connected to map and base_link connected to velodyne.

Recorded at time: 1427157851.432
world
base_link
Broadcaster: /world_to_map
Average rate: 99.505 Hz
Most recent transform: 1573667449.140 ( -146509597.709 sec old)
Buffer length: 4.985 sec
map
Broadcaster: /base_link_to_localizer
Average rate: 99.533 Hz
Most recent transform: 1573667449.141 ( -146509597.710 sec old)
Buffer length: 4.983 sec
velodyne

2. don't know how to attach screen shot here

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-13**:
3) Rviz error: TF: No transform from [base_link] to frame [world]
No transform from [velodyne] to frame [world]
Points Raw:
For frame [velodyne]: No transform to fixed frame [world].  TF error: [Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1427157850.433733120 but the earliest data is at time 1573666846.142417109, when looking up transform from frame [velodyne] to frame [world]]

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-14**:
@avdev Thank you for giving the information. If possible, could you upload the data to Google Drive or some online storage services and share the link?

As for the error, I think the cause is you are launching nodes BEFORE starting rosbag play.
When we play rosbag, rosparam `use_sim_time` will be true.
We need to launch nodes after that in order to use the simulation time.

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-17**:
Kenji-

Thanks for the feedback.

I tired it again making sure to start the rosbag play before launching the map node.  I am not sure how to check the use_sim_time.

Here are the screen shots and .pdf you asked for.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fkE1XuuLg_w_SQFdljGpYLVUIDAYQaJJ?usp=sharing

A second problem that I did not mention earlier is that RuntimeManager has screen tearing making it hard to do more than 2 steps.  Any ideas there?

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-17**:
also I did not find the tf.launch in sample moriyama data but used this instead for #2 in your suggestions.
/home//autoware.ai/src/autoware/documentation/autoware_quickstart_examples/launch/tf_local.launch

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-18**:
@avdev Thank you for the additional information.

> I am not sure how to check the use_sim_time.

It's automatically set if you use `runtime_manager`.
This message will be shown in the console: `['rosparam', 'set', '/use_sim_time', 'true']`.

> RuntimeManager has screen tearing

It's a known issue in Autoware.AI v1.12 and currently fixed. https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/utilities/issues/2
There are 3 options to fix this.

1. Use `master` instead of v1.12
2. Apply patch to `runtime_manager` according to the MR
3. Wait until v1.13 is released (the beginning of December)

> I did not find the tf.launch

Please see this page carefully.
https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/ROSBAG-Demo

You can download the `tf.launch` with map files from this link.
`1. Download the sample 3D pointcloud/vector map data. [link]`

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-21**:
Screen tearing is fixed when using the "master" branch.
I now have tf.launch and reference it in TF map.  As well as clicking TF in Setup.  But still no RViz display.  See screenshots from _191121.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13_ihoSFdrodrypkyhQsMyWZbr4YeWrg3

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-22**:
Could you show me the output of `rosnode list`? I think you forgot running `ndt_mapping` (or, `ndt_matching`). It's publishing the TF between `map` to `base_link`.

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-23**:
/base_link_to_localizer
/play_1574545125653620476
/rosout
/runime_manager_2761_1574544625473
/rviz_1574544661393343287

still no point cloud in RViz.  I tried ndt_mapping, ndt_matching, and both together, all with the TF clicked on setup and map tabs.

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-24**:
Probably it's not working. You need to publish PointCloud to make `ndt_*` work.
Could you record your operation video?

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-24**:
Kenji - I really appreciate your help.

I am not sure how to publish PointCloud.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fkE1XuuLg_w_SQFdljGpYLVUIDAYQaJJ
Link contains the video (Screencast 2019-11-24 10:43:49.mp4) and frames_191124.pdf.

rosnode list produced this...
/base_link_to_localizer
/joint_state_publisher
/play_1574609981197388211
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
/runime_manager_7398_1574609949157
/rviz_1574609986881583137

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-24**:
Oh, I'm sorry, there was a mistake. When you use `ndt_mapping`, you don't need PointCloud because you will create it with `ndt_mapping`.
So, you need to check why it's not running and not found in `rosnode list`.
Are there any messages printed your runtime_manager's terminal when you activate the checkbox of ndt_mapping?

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-24**:
By the way, you can publish PointCloud just by selecting the PointCloud file, which is included in sample_moriyama_data.tar.gz, in `Map` tab.
To check published correctly, run `rostopic echo /poits_map`.

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-24**:
@avdev I've checked your video, thank you very much for taking it!
I found there was an error message `RLException: [ndt_mapping]...` at around 3:30.
It's probably because `ndt_mapping.launch` was not found in your built files.

Can you `roscd lidar_localizer`, and is there `~/autoware.ai/install/.../lidar_localizer/launch/ndt_mapping.launch`?

Could you let me know the result of these commands?

```
sudo updatedb
locate ndt_mapping.launch
```

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-24**:
I went to map tab and loaded 1 of the many .pcd files in the /.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00169_-00868.pcd

points did not appear in RViz

$ rostopic echo /points_map
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?

$ roscd lidar_localizer
roscd: No such package/stack 'lidar_localizer'

The only location of the files is in home/autoware.ai/src/autoware/core_perception/lidar_localizer/launch/ndt.mapping.launch

$ sudo updatedb
$ locate ndt_mapping.launch
/home/todd/autoware.ai/src/autoware/core_perception/lidar_localizer/launch/approximate_ndt_mapping.launch
/home/todd/autoware.ai/src/autoware/core_perception/lidar_localizer/launch/ndt_mapping.launch

$ sudo updatedb locate ndt_mapping_launch
updatedb: unexpected operand on command line

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-24**:
Sorry for the confusion. These are two commands.
$ sudo updatedb # Updateting index, actually not necessary, but just to be sure
$ locate ndt_mapping.launch # List the paths of files named ndt_mapping.launch
-> autoware.ai/install/lidar_localizer/share/lidar_localizer/launch/ndt_mapping.launch

However, it became non-necessary now, because I can guess your status from other results.

Also, seeing your `roscd` result, you didn't build Autoware.AI correctly.
Please try these commands and check if built correctly. (stderr output is okay)

```
$ cd ~/autoware.ai
$ colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
... long build messages
Summary: 164 packages finished [8min 51s]
49 packages had stderr output: ...
```

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-24**:
If you can't build, please check the dependencies are installed.

```
$ cd ~/autoware.ai
$ rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-25**:
Thanks Kenji.  I am new to Ubuntu and new to Autoware.

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-11-25**:
Tried to build autoware 3 more times and the third was successful. Here are the videos but the demo still does not show the map. They are the 2 screencasts with the date 11-25.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fkE1XuuLg_w_SQFdljGpYLVUIDAYQaJJ

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-11-25**:
Please try this, which clears the cache of runtime_manager:

```
cd ~/autoware.ai
rm -rf ./install/runtime_manager
colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Also, could you give me additional information to check your build environment?

```
$ gcc -v
...
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.10.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-12-04**:
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
cmake version 3.10.2

**Comment by [avdev](https://answers.ros.org/users/49318/avdev/) on 2019-12-04**:
Built it with colcon 1x but it had errors.  Built it a 2nd time with the same command and only got this warning.

Starting >>> state_machine_lib
[7.064s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_cmake.task.cmake.build:Could not run installation step for package 'ndt_gpu' because it has no 'install' target

But the demo worked!!!
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11egzNfX_U-GxqgBgqvwsHMKmwyIKShT_
Screencast 2019-12-04 19:30:25.mp4

Now to learn how to use Rviz & Autoware.

Thanks for your help Kenji.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recorded my operation and uploaded it to [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuALdB7tlSs&feature=youtu.be).

What I did are:

1. Download files from [here](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/ROSBAG-Demo)
2. Setup Autoware according to [this page](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build)

   - If you are using ROS Melodic, I recommend using master version instead of v1.12, or please wait v1.13 which will be released soon
3. Launch runtime_manager
4. Play and pause .bag file
5. Launch tf of velodyne and map

   - It seemed ndt_mapping requires velodyne-tf BEFORE ndt_mapping
6. Launch ndt_mapping
7. Launch Rviz
8. Cancel the pause of .bag file
9. Velodyne's points can be seen in Rviz

---

Originally posted by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) with karma: 307 on 2019-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scarlet191101](https://answers.ros.org/users/48518/scarlet191101/) on 2019-12-03**:
Thank you,Kenji Miyake.

I have been able to execute it a while ago, and I'm sorry to respond to it until now.

First, I started testing from the bag file.

Encountered rviz crashes, so I changed to a computer to test.

Now it can be successfully executed, and also successfully executed with its own bag file.

I've recorded my operation and uploaded it to [here](https://www.youtube.com/watchv=DmNnPzaBrqU&feature=youtu.be)